# How was the return of Clark Kent explained?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

In the new *Justice League* movie, we see that:

> Superman is revived by being placed in a Kryptonian Regeneration Matrix.

It is pretty understandable that this can be explained to the public, as one such event has occurred in *[Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_v_Superman:_Dawn_of_Justice)*. This is pretty easily explainable because he is not a human and many things are still unknown about him.

Having said so,

> With the death of Superman, Clark Kent was also dead and we see a detailed funeral service. When Superman came back, how do they explain the return of Clark Kent, who is assumed to be just another human being, working in the Daily Planet?

Comment: "Hi everyone, I'm back. Yeah, I was so shaken after everything that happened, I went on a cliché extended journey into the mountains to find myself. I had no contact with the outside world; sorry that you all thought I was dead. My mom needed closure, so she had a fake-burial and everything" _– Clark Kent (Man of Steel 2)_

Comment: They just say that it was Lois Lane's dream and Clark was in the shower all the time.  No wait,  that was *Dallas*.

Comment: Trouble with the "fake burial" theory is that the funeral held in Smallville in BvS was open-casket and everyone who attended saw Clark's corpse...

Comment: Then he was cremated, and he emerged with severe burn marks. No wait, that was _My Hero_.

Comment: Does "_I am Mark Kent, Clark's evil twin, and I have not come in peace !_" make a valid reason?

Comment: You beat me for this question. I wanted to ask it too... It bother me so much...

Comment: Maybe he was injured on a trip to the mountains and got lost.  The body in the casket was his long lost twin (the two were separated when they were adopted), who happened to die around the same time.  They thought the twin was Clark, so they didn't realize he was missing.  Once he healed up and hiked back to civilization they realized the mixup and he was brought "back to life", including his old job.

Comment: @DanSmolinske aha, this is enough content to make a new comic.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an opinion-based question.  If the answer was provided in the film, or in interviews, it can be added as an answer.  If it wasn't explained anywhere, then that's also an answer.

Comment: The short answer is **it wasn't**. As far as I know, we haven't seen Clark Kent return to his civilian life.

Comment: When Superman died in the comics, he "resurrected" Clark by pretending he'd been trapped in rubble since the fight against Doomsday. As I recall, a child had been rescued alive from a similar situation, which lead him to fake the situation for himself. It seemed a bit far-fetched (in terms of publishing, he'd been "dead" for months).